# how to make the empty rectangle in javascript programming?

Tags: javascript

Javascript:
Write function printEmptyRectangle(a, b), with a and b are two integers> 3,prints out an empty rectangle of size a x b. For example:
printEmptyRectangle(8,5):

```
********
*      *
*      *
*      *
********
```

Comment: Despite stackoverflow being and ask/answer community, the idea is to solve specific problems such as behavior or logic, please make an attempt yourself so we can guide you through the way of achieving success. Many people of here can answer the source code on how to do what you ask, but it would be 0 learning for you, give it a shot and come back!

Comment: Do you want a DOM element? Or are you using Canvas?? Please provide some code that shows what you have tried and what is failing.

Answer (score -1):

You can draw rectangle in p5.js in less line of code

```
// Draw a rectangle at location (30, 20) with a width and height of 55.
rect(30, 20, 55, 55);
```

for more reference you can visit [p5.js](https://p5js.org/reference/)

Comment: The OP made no mention of p5.js

Comment: but i suggested just another way